# Integrating platform specific code into Gluon Mobile project

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I would like to integrate some platform (Android) specific code into my Gluon Mobile project. So I imported the GoNative project into Eclipse as a new Gradle project in order to learn from it how to do that. The code itself is clear so far but why is Eclipse not able to resolve any Android code references. Is there anything wrong with the gradle scripts or did I miss something?

Comment: Eclipse fails to add the android dependencies. While it works fine on IntelliJ or NetBeans, for Eclipse, in this case you have to manually add your local `android.jar` to the project as external jar. You will find it under  your `<android sdk folder>/platforms/platform-<n>`.

Comment: Have you tried that? If I do that, Eclipse doesn't even find things like String anymore but it does find the things in the android.* namespace then.

Comment: Yes, I did. It works fine for me. I see the android.jar under `Referenced Libraries`.

Comment: It still does not work for the imported example which probably has something to do with Java 10 for which the example is not properly configured. But I got that working now in my real evaluation code which is configured correctly.